# How to get answers for multiple ques_ids in a single query in an questionnaire system in Django?

Tags: python, mysql, django, django-orm

There are 3 questions 
1. What is your Age?
2. What is your Gender?
3. Your Scale?
For which question ids are 3,6 and 9 respectively.

Answers model:

```
class Answer(models.Model):

    profile = models.ForeignKey(Profile, help_text=u'The user who supplied this answer')
    question = models.ForeignKey(Question, help_text=u"The question that this is an answer to")
    value_int = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True)
    value_str = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True, blank=True)
```

Value_int holds the answers for age(question id 3) and scale(question id 9)
and value_str holds the answer of gender (question id 6)

I want to query Answer model with a list of  profile ids.

I tried this:

```
users_age = Answer.objects.filter(question_id=age_question_id,
    profile_id__in=all_user_ids).values(
        'value_int',
        'profile__books__book_name')

users_gender = Answer.objects.filter(question_id=gender_question_id,
    profile_id__in=all_user_ids).values(
        'value_str',
        'profile__books__book_name')

users_scale = Answer.objects.filter(question_id=scale_question_id,
profile_id__in=all_user_ids).values(
     'value_int',
     'profile__books__book_name')
```

User ids are the just those who submitted those books, but the age,gender scale will be of the author. thus for a single profile id there might be more than one age ,gender or scale thus getting the book_name is mandatory.

Since there are a lot of records it takes huge time to get the result.
I want to optimize it and get the data in a single query such that,
for each book_name i can get the age,gender and scale values together not in different rows.
Please help me out to resolve this.

EDIT:

I tried using OR condition but the problem with the result set is it gives   multiple rows such that with the row having age answer will be having gender and sacle values as none.And gender answer row will have age and scale value none. And so on and its too much of data which creates duplicates and some missing.

Comment: Is there any way i can tag the django/python experts with so much of reputations to get the answer.

Comment: Please post all the models that are involved in the query, and a clear description of the results you are seeking